# jQuery selector for next unfocused input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have an input element `$myInput = $('#someInput')` within a paragraph. I would like to find the next input element in that paragraph which is unfocused.

I have tried `$myInput.next('input(:not(:focus))')` but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$myInput = $('input');
```

and then

```
$myInput.nextAll('input').not(':focus').eq(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

> $myInput.nextAll('input').not(':focus').first();